# Riddle: Life of the party

Tags: riddle

> All I remember was being at a store and then all of a sudden someone was taking me to this party!
>
> Some people couldn't stop staring at me. (Maybe they were impressed when I was holding onto everyone's drink!)
>
> Later that night, some guy slammed me onto the table and then started yelling, it was crazy.
>
> It was one wild night...but now that I'm older, things seem to be a little hazy.

What in the world could I possible be?

Hint:

> I'm not a human ;)

(I hope this isn't too easy for my first riddle, make sure your answer works with every line!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> (the) Glasses (Thanks @Rand al' Thor!)

All I remember was being at a store and then all of a sudden someone was taking me to this party!

> Buy glasses at the store, then take it to the party.

Some people couldn't stop staring at me. Maybe they were impressed when I was holding onto everyone's drink!

> People stare at glasses while toasting and always hold everyone's drink. Also people that wear 'glasses' can't stop staring at them.

Later that night, some guy slammed me onto the table and then started yelling, it was crazy.

> Finished his drink, then slammed the glass on the table. Yelled "woo! That's tasty!"

It was one wild night...but now that I'm older, things seem to be a little hazy.

> Glass gets hazy over the years :)

Comment: Not the EXACT answer I was looking for, you might be thinking a little too narrow.

Comment: Give it a bit :) I'm sure more will pop up

Comment: @MarkN More generally, could it be just a **glass/cup**?

Comment: Maybe it's a cocktail shaker? Not sure how it would fit with "things seem to be a little hazy" though.

Comment: When drinks get mixed, they can appear hazy with the different weights of alcohol in them. I immediately turn to the "Kamekazi" mixed up.. or a dirty martini

Comment: @BrianRobbins You're totally right. Hazy could also refer to a less "pure" drink because it's been mixed with other stuff.

Comment: Hrm... appropriate? Not sure. But I don't mind if you do :)

Answer (score 7):

Can't quite get one right on but:

> A bottle (of any drink).

I remember was being at a store and then all of a sudden someone was taking me to this party!

> Purchased at a store, taken to the party.

Some people couldn't stop staring at me. (Maybe they were impressed when I was holding onto everyone's drink!)

> Holding what people are drinking. There are always those that are only there to drink and will stare at whatever the drink is.

Later that night, some guy slammed me onto the table and then started yelling, it was crazy.

> A fight where people use bottles, or just a celebratory slam.

It was one wild night...but now that I'm older, things seem to be a little hazy.

> Glass bottles tend to fog or get hazzy with age.

Answer (score 2):

Let me see:

> A video camera

I remember was being at a store and then all of a sudden someone was taking me to this party!

> Purchased at a store, Taken to the party.

Some people couldn't stop staring at me. (Maybe they were impressed when I was holding onto everyone's drink!)

> People were staring at the video camera and the camera was focusing on their drinks, recording them perhaps.

Later that night, some guy slammed me onto the table and then started yelling, it was crazy.

> He was recording something on the camera.

It was one wild night...but now that I'm older, things seem to be a little hazy.

> Camera/Video camera lenses have become hazy with age.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be

> Ice

All I remember was being at a store and then all of a sudden someone was taking me to this party!

> Someone bought the ice bag

Some people couldn't stop staring at me. (Maybe they were impressed when I was holding onto everyone's drink!)

> Holding onto everyone's drink discards the camera, and leaves us bottles, glasses or ice

Later that night, some guy slammed me onto the table and then started yelling, it was crazy.

> Since ice starts to melt, we have to slam it in order to take ice chunks

It was one wild night...but now that I'm older, things seem to be a little hazy.

> As the party ends, the ice either melts or gets into a fridge, getting hazy in either a metaphorical or literal way.